# Remove C:\\fakepath\\ from file path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to remove `C:\\fakepath\\` from my file path when a user uploads a file in a reactive angular form.  I found this code online:

```
  selectFiles(event: any): void {
    // newchanges start
    this.filename = this.filename.split('C:\\fakepath\\')[1];
    // newchanges end
    var selectedFiles = event.target.files;

    if (selectedFiles && selectedFiles[0]) {
      const numberOfFiles = selectedFiles.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          console.log(e.target.result);
          this.imageUrl = e.target.result;
          this.filedata = {
            id: this.FileData.length + 1,
            data: event,
            // newchanges start
            filename: this.filename,
            // newchanges end
            filescr: e.target.result,
          };
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFiles[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

When I try to append the file before I submit I still get the file path.

```
payload.append('file', this.filename , this.filename .name);
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at this piece of code I might not have all the information to answer.
I can tell you this, to be absolutely sure that the value of `this.filename` its not being modified by external sources you can set a variable `newFileName` and use the new variable to assign the value to the payload.

However I had a hard time understanding how filename its being used on the code since I don't know when the original value is being set.

You should share more infos when making the questions.